# how to call set time out function

Tags: jquery

Using set time out function how to redirect the page to my admin home page I am trying to submit form by using jquery.

In php i use header location admin index php page  but how to redirect it in this jquery form can some one help me with this code.

```
 <form method="POST" class="login" action="">
    <p class="title">Log in</p>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" autofocus/>
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
    <a href="forgotpassword.php">Forgot your password?</a>
    <button>
      <i class="spinner"></i>
      <span class="state"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Log in"></span>
    </button>
  </form>

var working = false;
$('.login').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (working) return;
  working = true;
  var $this = $(this),
    $state = $this.find('button > .state');
  $this.addClass('loading');
  $state.html('Authenticating');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $this.addClass('ok');
    $state.html('Welcome back!');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $state.html('Log in');
      $this.removeClass('ok loading');
      working = false;
    }, 4000);
  }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: i suggest you use ajax. if ajax is success you direct the page to where you want if fail you do the same

Comment: window.location.href = 'adminpage.php'

Comment: Thanks mohammed Yousef... But can u plz tell me exactly where to put these lines i mean 
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.location.href='admin/index.php';
      $this.removeClass('ok loading');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this code:

```
setTimeout(function() {
      $state.html('Log in');
      $this.removeClass('ok loading');
      working = false;
    }, 4000);
```

to this one:

```
setTimeout(function() {
      $state.html('Log in');
      $this.removeClass('ok loading');
      working = false;
      window.href.location = 'adminpage.php';
    }, 4000);
```

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to admin page, you can use window.location.href = 'adminpage.php'

```
$('.login').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this),
    $state = $this.find('button > .state');
  $this.addClass('loading');
  $state.html('Authenticating');
//Use Ajax here to validate login
//if validate success:
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.href.location = 'adminpage.php';
    }, 4000);
//if failed: alert('login failed.')
  }, 3000);
});
```

Please learn about Ajax, I think you do not understand the flow.